# How do I add a custom phtml file in the product page issue

Tags: layout, magento-1

In my custom module in the config.xml file I added my layout:

```
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mynamespace_mymodule>
                    <file>mynamespace_mymodule.xml</file>
                </mynamespace_mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
```

In my mynamespace_mymodule.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="impressions" template="mynamespace/mymodule/impressions.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

The content of impressions.phtml is a simple html: `<p>Test</p>`, but when I access the product page , my "Test" doesn't show up. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Please check your system.log or exception.log file. If there is any problem in your code it will reflect in log.

Comment: Use `type="core/template"` if you want to show additional custom content.  `catalog/product_view` is meant for the main block of the product detail page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" output="toHtml" name="impressions" template="mynamespace/mymodule/impressions.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: content is core/tesxt_list block that render all child blocks by default

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" after="-" name="impressions" output="toHtml" template="mynamespace/mymodule/impressions.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: nope :(  It doesn't work. Any other ideas ?

Comment: I update my answer! check now and let me know

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your extension was enabled
2. What is location of layout and template file. If it's not in base package and not in active package and theme it wouldn't be work

Comment: the extension it is enabled. it it is design/frontend/base/default/layout/mynamespace_mymodule.xml

Comment: do you clear or disable cache?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instruction and check it.

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mynamespace_mymodule> <!-- needs to match frontName tag -->
                <file>mynamespace_mymodule.xml</file>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```